# How can I make the browsing file upload window to show only the .jpg images?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a form that allow image uploading. However my code until now is not limited to images.

Please let me know how can I do this (maybe with a javascript alert box on submit) or my best solution is to let the browsing window to show only jpg gif and png images instead of the default "All files".

Thanks!

```
<input name="images[]" value="" type="file" class="textfield" />
```

Comment: Nope. `10 more to go! oh 580 chars left`

Comment: It works pretty well in Opera `<input type=file accept="image/*">`

Comment: @mario I tested it but not working on Firefox though. Maybe a js that checks will be my solution

Comment: Just tested it with Firefox4, that works nicely too. Chrome OTOH just recognizes the option, but does not filter the directory listings.

Comment: `<input type=file accept="image/*">` This works on Chrome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control what is shown in the browser's file upload form. The best option is to implement some client or server side validation on the file's extension.

Comment: please try to upload your image on facebook you can't select any other file which are not image.
<input type="file" accept="image/*"> to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to validate the file extension, also you must validate in server side.

Another option is you can try SWFUpload- a flash JS library for uploading files. It has a feature to validate files type and file sizes before uploading to server.
http://swfupload.org/